# Euler vs Runge-Kutta for projectile motion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, classical-mechanics, runge-kutta-methods, computational-science

I've got to solve numerically the projectile motion equations with the Euler method and the Runge-Kutta 4th order method. Although my codes (Matlab) work, i keep getting exactly the same answers from both of the methods whereas i should get a more accurate answer from the second one. What am i doing wrong? I am supposed to compare the accuracy of the two methods with respect to time (for the same given n) and to the range of the time step. Thank you.
[Runge-Kutta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1kV4.png)
[Euler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2Ekd.png)

Comment: Please post the relevant code parts as text, not as image. You posted the same code in both images, that of the semi-implicit Euler method, of course that will result in identical results.

Comment: Sorry, first time here. I just copy-paste my code in the comment section? @LutzL

Comment: @Gaussian-Integral Don't you realize that your two codes are exactly the same?

Comment: yeah i sent the wrong one on the first image sorry, gonna send the correct one now @velutluna

Comment: No, leave the comments as comments, add substantial information to the question by editing it as you did for the link correction. If necessary add some kind of time stamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The semi-implicit or symplectic Euler method that you implemented has order 2 if the initialization is compatible with the leapfrog-Verlet method. The exact solution of this problem is a polynomial of degree 2. Thus this Euler method is exact up to floating point noise. Of course also the RK4 method is exact in the same way.

Add a suitable friction term to get a solution that is no longer polynomial and will thus have different results between the methods. Or implement the Euler method properly so that it is the explicit order 1 variant.

Comment: Thanks for the in depth response. The next question in the exercise is asking me to compute the initial angle for which i get maximum range, but this time adding the friction. So i guess i will then see a change between the two methods.

Comment: Check again what the first task demands, if it is the explicit Euler method then your implementation is definitely wrong.

Comment: It just say Euler method..

Comment: Then it is the explicit Euler method, all derivatives have to have their value at time $t$, your code uses a derivative at $t+dt$ in `v_y`.

Comment: So i should instead write v_y(1)=v_0*sin(theta) and v_y(i+1) = v_y(i) + dt*(-g) inside the loop? Thanks.

Comment: I get the same answer though.

Comment: The important point is that `y(i+1)` is computed using `v_y(i)`.

Comment: I wrote  y(i+1) = y(i) + dt*v_y(i); but i got the same thing

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple errors in the code.

As already noted in the earlier answer, your "Euler" code is not the simple Euler algorithm you were meant to implement. To get the simple Euler algorithm,
change the body of the loop so you set `v_y` after `y(i+1)`, not before.

Another mistake is that the last coordinates predicted by the loop are `x(N+1)` and `y(N+1)`, but you use `x(N)` and `y(N)` instead.
Since you perform `N` timesteps (`for i = 1:N`), 
and the initial coordinates are `x(1)` and `y(1)`, 
the correct final coordinates are indeed `x(N+1)` and `y(N+1)`.

You could also check this by comparing your results against the known closed-form solution for projectile motion under the equations of motion you assumed.
You would find that your "maximum range" is shorter than predicted;
in fact it is shorter by exactly one timestep times `v_x`.

Finally, you neglect to print out the final altitude, which is really the only interesting prediction, since the only acceleration you have is in the vertical direction.
Of course both methods are guaranteed to get the same results for "maximum range," since both methods perform the same number of timesteps of the same elapsed time with the same constant $x$-velocity.
I get very different altitudes at the end of the last timestep, however.

Specifically, with an initial speed of $100$ meters per second and angle $45$ degrees, with $15$ timesteps, the final altitude (`y(16)`)
is $66.6666$ meters according to the simple Euler method,
$-66.6666$ meters according to "Euler" method you implemented,
and $2.84217 \times 10^{-14}$ meters
(that is, zero with the usual accumulated floating-point arithmetic error)
according to your Runge-Kutta implementation.

For the record, I OCRed the program listings you posted in order to reproduce your results. Here is what I got for the Euler script after cleaning up the scan:

```
g = 10;
v_0 = input('Enter initial velocity (m/s): ');
theta = degtorad(input('Enter initial angle from the ground (degrees): '));
N = input('Enter number of steps: ');
x(1) = 0;
v_x = v_0*cos(theta);
y(1) = 0;
v_y = v_0*sin(theta);
t(1) = 0; %Initial time
toliko = 2*v_y/g;
dt = toliko/N; %Time step
counter = 0; %counter

for i = 1:N; %Euler method
    x(i+1) = x(i) + dt*v_x;
    v_y = v_y + dt*(-g);
    y(i+1) = y(i) + dt*v_y;
    t(i+1) = i*dt;
    counter = counter + 1;
end

fprintf("\n\nMaximum range is %g meters\n", x(N));
fprintf("Total time is %g seconds\n", t(N));
fprintf("counter = %f\n", counter);

plot(x,y, "k—");
xlabel('x ');
ylabel('y ');
title('Projectile motion')
```

And here is what I got for the Runge-Kutta script:

```
g = 10;
v_0 = input('Enter initial velocity (m/s): '));
theta = degtorad(input('Enter initial angle from the ground (degrees): '));
N = input('Enter number of steps: ');
x(1) = 0;
v_x(1) = v_0*cos(theta);
y(1) = 0;
v_y(1) = v_o*sin(theta);
toliko = 2*v_y(1)/g; %How long to integrate for (2nd time that y_1 = 0)
t(1) = 0; %Initial time
dt = toliko/N; %Time step
counter = 0;

for n = 1:N; %Runge-Kutta 4th order method
    t(n+1) = n*dt;

    k1 = dt*v_x(n);
    m1 = dt*0;
    L1 = dt*(v_y(n));
    Z1 = dt*(-g);

    k2 = dt*(v_x(n)+m1/2);
    m2 = dt*0;
    L2 = dt*(v_y(n)+ Z1/2);
    Z2 = dt*(-g);

    k3 = dt*(v_x(n)+m2/2);
    m3 = dtaro;
    L3 = dt*(v_y(n)+ Z2/2);
    Z3 = dt*(-g);

    k4 = dt*(v_x(n)+ m3);
    m4 = dt*0;
    L4 = dt*(v_y(n)+ Z3);
    Z4 = dt*(-g);

    x(n+1) = x(n)+1/6*(k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4);
    v_x(n+1) = v_x(n)+1/6*(m1 + 2*m2 + 2*m3 + m4);
    y(n+1) = y(n)+1/6*(L1 + 2*L2 + 2*L3 + L4);
    v_y(n+1) = v_y(n)+1/6*(Z1 + 2*Z2 + 2*Z3 + Z4);

    counter = counter + 1;
end

fprintf("\n\nMaximum range is %g meters\n", x(N));
fprintf("Total time is %g seconds\n", t(N));
fprintf("counter = %f\n", counter);
plot(x,y, 'k-');
xlabel('x ');
ylabel('y ');
title('Projectile motion')
```

I did not correct the errors in these copies of the scripts, so they still modify `v_y` too early in the "Euler" loop and still use the subscript `N` instead of the correct subscript `N+1` in the printed results at the end.